# Jekyll adding extra BR elements after line break in markdown

Tags: markdown, jekyll, redcarpet

Jekyll is adding an extra `<br>` element after line breaks in my `.md` file, within blocks intended to be paragraphs.  I notice this seems to happen mostly when I break the line after a period (`.`) .    Line breaks anywhere else don't have this issue.

Any idea why this is happening?  I haven't had this problem with other kinds of markdown before. 
For example, StackOverflow doesn't behave that way.

My `_config.yml` is using `markdown: redcarpet` and does not have any other markdown-related config so I don't think this applies ([Jekyll converting every newline as line break](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25418399/jekyll-converting-every-newline-as-line-break)).  Also, the redcarpet docs say that `hard_wrap` is default false.

Comment: What did you call *main paragraph text* ?

Comment: main text block intended to be paragraph blocks.